# Aussprache von '/'. Auch welcher Artikel soll man benutzen?

Tags: word-choice

> z.B. Licht ist eine Welle/Partikel

*Frage 1*: Wie soll man '/' aussprechen?

*Frage 2*: Wenn die Wörter verschiedene Geschlechter haben (wie oben), welcher Artikel soll man benutzen?

Comment: Es widerstrebt mir das auszusprechen. Du solltest eine andere Formulierung zum Welle-Teilchen-Dualismus wählen. Mit Müh und Not würde ich für / eine kleine Pause einlegen.

Comment: In not so formal settings, I regularly hear people say "Schrägstrich". I think it's completely fine to do that.

Comment: Off-topic but maybe useful: In German, "Licht" is a "Welle" or a "Teilchen", not a "Partikel". "Partikeln" are usually macroscopic ("Staubpartikel") or microscopic ("Nanopartikel") objects consisting of many atoms. Single fundamental particles such as electrons, protons, quarks, photons ("light"), are called "Teilchen".

Answer (score 3):

An Stellen, an denen es Schwierigkeiten macht die richtige Kurzform zu finden, sollte man einfach lang schreiben:
`Licht ist eine Welle bzw. ein Partikel`
Wobei du dir hier natürlich ein Beispiel ausgesucht hast, bei dem man über den Inhalt lange diskutieren könnte.

Comment: "beziehungsweise/bzw." wird zwar umgangssprachlich sehr häufig so verwendet, ist aber streng genommen falsch. Besser wäre hier "und" oder "oder" zu verwenden. Siehe: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-beziehungsweise-genauer-gesagt-a-308818.html

Comment: @RomanReiner This case is not as simple as those from the article. Using *und* or *oder* doesn't make it more correct.

Comment: @RomanReiner Danke für den wertvollen Link!

Answer (score 3):

1. Im Allgemeinen wird `/` als Schrägstrich oder beziehungsweise ausgesprochen. `Zum Beispiel Licht ist eine Welle Schrägstrich Partikel`
2. Der Artikel richtet sich nach dem ersten Wort und wird beim zweiten weggelassen.

Comment: Das würde man aber in einer Präsentation so nicht machen. Hier würde man der Kürzer halber schreiben "Welle/Partikel", dann aber je nach Kontext sagen "sowohl Welle als auch Partikel" oder "Welle oder Partikel" oder "Welle und Partikel" oder "Welle respektive Partikel", etc.

Answer (score 3):

Zu den Fragen:

1. Wenn Du den Text nur vorlesen sollst, dann liest man '/' als 'Schrägstrich'.
2. Wenn die Wörter verschiedene Geschlechter haben, sollte man beide Artikel verwenden.

Zum Stil:

Im informellen geschriebenen Text wird die grammatikalische Schlamperei als Verkürzung vielleicht noch durchgehen (schön ist anders), besser wäre, mindestens beide Artikel zu benutzen: *Licht ist **eine** Welle / **ein** Partikel* oder statt des Schrägstrichs ein passendes Bindewort o. Ä. zu benutzen. Das erlaubt auch eine Schärfung der Satzaussage. 
 In Deinem Beispiel:

- *Licht ist eine Welle **und** ein Partikel* oder
- *Licht ist eine Welle **oder** ein Partikel* oder
- *Licht ist eine Welle **bzw.** ein Partikel*.
- …